# Providing a large request example data fails in FastAPI

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, pydantic

In FastAPI, we can [declare request example data](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/). In my case, I am reading (JSON) data from the file system and the data is about 4 MB in size. I have no control over this data and it is a sample given to me.

Here is my code to read the data.

```
def get_examples():
    with open('./data/allData.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    examples = {
        'Sample Data': {
            'summary': 'External supplied vendor data.',
            'description': 'Test data.',
            'value': data
        }
    }
    return examples
```

My endpoint is defined as follows.

```
@app.post('/v1/parse')
def parse(data: TheData = Body(..., examples=get_examples())) -> TheOutput:
    return parser_service.parse(data)
```

The classes `TheData` and `TheOutput` are very basic. `TheData` is what I have no control over and it is highly nested without a schema (it is coming from the outside); although I do know the top level keys (there's only 3 of them).

```
class TheData(BaseModel):
    section1: Dict[Any, Any]
    section2: Dict[Any, Any]
    section3: Dict[Any, Any]

class TheOutput(BaseModel):
    field1: str
    field2: str
    # and so on
    field100: str
```

My problem is that when I go to the interactive documents at `/docs` and click on `/v1/parse` and try to execute the endpoint with the example input data, the web UI hangs (progress circle stops, web page stops). No errors or exceptions is shown in the console.

Is there a known limit on the size of the example JSONs/data that can be used in FastAPI?

I also went to [Pydantic's website](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/) and tried the `schema_extra()` approach, and got the same behavior.

Any ideas?

I am thinking this has something to do with the file size (4 MB) because when I modify `allData.json` to be very small, it works.

```
{
 "section1": "test1",
 "section2": "test2",
 "section3": "test3"
}
```

Comment: Maybe is a swagger limitation. Try to send your data using another tool like postman and see if it works.

Comment: Invoking the REST endpoint works programmatically (and is very fast) from Angular and curl. It must be something dealing with the UI or swagger as you stated.